# Integration of exponential functions and cosine function

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I am trying to solve the following equation;
$$\int_{-1}^{1}e^{i(x+a\cos x)} \, \mathrm{d}(\cos x)$$ or $$\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{i(x+a\cos x)} \sin x \, \mathrm{d}x$$

I tried this in *Wolfram Alpha*, but it says that answer cannot be obtained.

Comment: How did you arrive at this problem? Integration by parts? What is the original problem?

Comment: Mathematica can't do anything with this either.

Comment: Looks related to the incomplete Bessel function...

Comment: @ MPW original problem takes the form of the second expression. I transformed in into the first expression. any help on this is highly appreciated

Comment: Power series for the exponential and then integrate each term by parts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $F(a)$ be defined as

$$F(a)=\int_0^{\pi}e^{i(x+a\cos x)}\sin x\,dx \tag 1$$

Now, it is easy to show that the real part of $F$ is identically $0$.  To do this, we write the real part of $(1)$ as

$$\text{Re}\lbrace F(a)\rbrace=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(x+a\cos x)\sin x\,dx+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\cos(x+a\cos x)\sin x\,dx \tag 2$$

Then, enforcing the substitution $x\to \pi -x$ in the second integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\text{Re}\lbrace F(a)\rbrace&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(x+a\cos x)\sin x\,dx+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(\pi-x+a\cos (\pi-x))\sin (\pi-x)\,dx\\\\
& =\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(x+a\cos x)\sin x\,dx-\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(x+a\cos x)\sin x\,dx\\\\
&=0 \tag 3
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown.  We can write, therefore, $F(a)$ as

$$\begin{align}
F(a)&=i\int_0^{\pi}\sin(x+a\cos x)\sin x\,dx \\\\
&=i\int_0^{\pi}\left(\sin^2(x)\cos(a\cos x)+\sin(x)\cos(x)\sin(a\cos x)\,\right)dx\tag 4
\end{align}$$

where we arrived at the right-hand side of $(4)$ using a parallel development that led to $(3)$.

---

The second integral on the right-hand side of $(4)$ is easily evaluated.  Substituting $x\to \cos(x)$ and integrating by parts reveals that

$$\begin{align}
i\int_0^{\pi}\sin(x)\cos(x)\sin(a\cos x)\,dx&=i2\int_{0}^1 x\sin(ax)\,dx\\\\
&=i2\frac{-a\cos(a)+\sin(a)}{a^2} \tag 5
\end{align}$$

Using $(5)$ in $(4)$ reduces $F(a)$ to

$$\begin{align}
F(a)&=i\int_0^{\pi}\left(\sin^2(x)\cos(a\cos x)\right)\,dx\\\\
&+i2\frac{-a\cos(a)+\sin(a)}{a^2} \tag 6
\end{align}$$

---

In order to evaluate the integral in $(6)$ we will enforce two successive substitutions.  First, we let $a\cos x\to x$.  This yields

$$i\int_0^{\pi}\left(\sin^2(x)\cos(a\cos x)\right)=\frac{i2}{a}\int_0^a
\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{u}{a}\right)^2} \cos (x)\,dx$$

where we exploited the fact that the integrand is an even function.  Next, we enforce the substitution $x\to a\sin x$ which reveals

$$\begin{align}
i\int_0^{\pi}\left(\sin^2(x)\cos(a\cos x)\right)&=i\int_0^{\pi}\cos^2(x)\cos(a\sin x)\,dx \tag 7\\\\
&=i\int_0^{\pi}\cos(a\sin x)\,dx-i\int_0^{\pi}\sin^2(x)\cos(a\sin x)\,dx\\\\
&=i\pi J_0(a)+i\pi J_1'(a)\\\\
&=i\pi\frac{J_1(a)}{a} \tag 8
\end{align}$$

where $J_0(a$) and $J_1(a)$ are the [Bessel Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) of the first kind and order zero and one, respectively, while $J_1'(a)$ is the first derivative of $J_1$.  In deriving $(8)$ we relied on Equations $(B5)$, $(B6)$, and $(B8)$ in the section on Bessel Functions.

Aside, we exploited the symmetry of $\cos^2(x)\cos(a\sin x)$ around $\pi/2$ to arrive at $(7)$.

---

**FINAL RESULT**

Putting $(6)$ and $(8)$ together finally yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{F(a)=i2\frac{-a\cos(a)+\sin(a)}{a^2}+i\pi\frac{J_1(a)}{a}} $$

which agrees with the empirically obtained hypothesis of @ClaudeLeibovici and @JoshBroadhurst!

---

**BESSEL FUNCTION ASIDE**

We note an integral representation for the first kind Bessel Function of order $n$

$$\begin{align}
J_n(a)&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\cos(nx-a\sin x)dx \\\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \left(\cos (nx)\cos(a\sin x)+\sin(nx)\sin(a\sin x)\right) \,dx \tag{B1}
\end{align}$$

along with recurrence relationships

$$J_n(a)=\frac{a}{2n}\left(J_{n-1}(a)+J_{n+1}(a)\right) \tag{B2}$$

and

$$J_n'(a)=\frac12
\begin{cases}
J_{n-1}(a)-J_{n+1}(a),&n\ne 0\\\\
-J_1(a),&n = 0 \tag{B4}
\end{cases}$$

Setting $n=0$ in $(B1)$ yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{J_0(a)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \left(\cos(a\sin x)\right) \,dx} \tag{B5}$$

Taking the two derivatives of $J_0(a)$ and multiplying by $-1$ and using $(B4)$ yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{J_1'(a)=-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \sin^2(x)\cos(a\sin x)\,dx}\tag{B6}$$

Note that using $(B3)$ and $(B4)$, we can eliminate $J_{n+1}$ and write $J_n$ as

$$J_n(a)=\frac{a}{n}\left(J_{n-1}(a)-J_n'(a)\right) \tag{B7}$$

Setting $n=1$ in $(B7)$ and rearranging we obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{J_1(a)}{a}=J_0(a)+J_1'(a)} \tag{B8}$$

---

Comment: Bravissimo, my friend !

Comment: @Dr. MV wow..thanks heaps :)

Comment: @user50724 You're welcome.  My pleasure.  I must admit that I went through a couple of dead ends before the light went on.  And the development might have a much faster way forward.  The key was the effective substitution $\cos x\to \sin x$.   I did this in two steps, but probably should have done it in one.  And perhaps this could have been enforced up front without the need to split out the real and imaginary parts.  But it worked!

Comment: @ Dr. MV Many thanks,I have a few more calculations similar to this. Thanks for this method :). I learnt alot

Comment: You're really quite welcome.  I am still recovering at home from surgery 3 weeks ago.  Your comment really means a lot to me.

Comment: @Dr.MV, very very nice. +1 from me, and I hope your recovery goes well! :-)

Comment: @Dr.MV I wish you a speedy recovery

Comment: @zainpatel Thank you! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @user50724 Thank you for the wish!  That means a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you leave out the (what I assume is a) constant $a$ in your original problem and type it into WolframAlpha, it tells you that the solution involves the Bessel function of the first kind ($J_1$) and gives the following answer
$$ (\pi J_1(1)-2 \cos(1)+2 \sin(1))i \approx 1.9848i$$

If you set $a=2$ as the input to WolframAlpha this gives
$$ \frac{1}{2} (\pi J_1(2)-2 \cos(2)+\sin(2))i \approx 1.7767i$$

Again with $a=3$ as the input gives
$$ \frac{1}{9} (3 \pi J_1(3)-6 \cos(3)+2 \sin(3))i \approx 1.0464i$$

Perhaps you can use a few more values for $a$ and generalize a pattern. 
The input I'm using looks like:

```
integrate from 0 to pi: e^(i (x + 3 cosx)) sinx dx
```

Hopefully this is sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help

Comment: @joshbroadhurst OK. After a few failed dead ends, I finally got it!!!

Answer (score 1):

In the same spirit as Josh Broadhurst's answer, you should arrive to $$\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{i(x+a\cos(x))} \sin(x)\,dx=\frac{\pi  a J_1(a)-2 a \cos (a)+ 2 \sin (a)}{a^2}\,i$$  I do not find  any way to compute the antiderivative itself.

Comment: many thanks for this generalized answer.

Comment: You are very welcome ! The pattern was quite clear from Josh Broadhurst's answer.

Comment: Yes.I did not try this method (Josh Broadhurst method in the answer) previously, when Alpha fails to give an answer. Now I know a small trick :).

Comment: However, I I have no idea about the middle steps, how they have arrived with the answer. May be I should next try with Mathematica .

Comment: Do it and let me know ? I am just curious. But, again, I seriously doubt that the antiderivative could have a closed form.

Comment: Yes same here. I shall let you know if Mathematica  gives a proper answer with steps. Thanks

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici I tried this in Mathematica, however it too does not show any middle steps :(

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, perhaps Jack could shed some light here? :-)

Comment: @ZainPatel I am sure we can get this one.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  Hello my friend!  Hope you are well.  OK. After a few failed dead ends, I finally got it!!!

Comment: @ZainPatel OK.  I got it!!